# PHP table wont show

Tags: php, html

i am trying to  output a table in PHP but for some reason it don't show i have an error in the syntax i don't get it if some can help it will be great:

```
<div id="Body1">
<?php
  echo " <table width="800" border="0" align="center"> ";
  echo " <tr> <td height="106" id="main" style="background-image: url(img/bk01.jpg); background-repeat: x;"> </td> </tr> ";
  echo " <tr> <td >   </td> </tr> ";
  echo " <tr><td height="606" id="main" style="background-image: url(img/bk02.jpg); background-repeat: x;" >";  include 'menu.php' echo"</td> </tr> ";
  echo " <tr> <td ></td></tr> ";
  echo" <tr><td height="49" id="Footer" style="background-image: url(img/bk03.gif); background-repeat: x;"> &nbsp; </td> </tr> ";
  echo"</table>";
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Show the full error message and tell us which line in your code corresponds to which line in the error message.

Answer (score 3):

Change the " within the Echo's " " to '.

E.g.

```
<?php echo " <table width='800' border='0' align='center'>";?>
```

Comment: echo "stuff" and echo 'stuff' both behave slightly differently so it might be worth reading up on the differences. Either way, you have to be careful as echo "hello "there" sir"; will NOT work as the interpreter picks it up as echo "hello " then it will error as it will encounter an unknown keyword 'there'.

Answer (score 3):

Please take care while using `""` and `''` in PHP.

Your code should rather be something like this:

```
<?php echo " <table width='800' border='0' align='center'> "; OR 
<?php echo ' <table width="800" border="0" align="center"> ';
```

Answer (score 2):

change double quotes to single quotes as wrapper:

```
<div id="Body1">
<?php
  echo ' <table width="800" border="0" align="center"> ';
  echo ' <tr> <td height="106" id="main" style="background-image: url(img/bk01.jpg); background-repeat: x;"> </td> </tr> ';
  echo ' <tr> <td >   </td> </tr> ';
  echo ' <tr><td height="606" id="main" style="background-image: url(img/bk02.jpg); background-repeat: x;" >';
  include 'menu.php';
  echo '</td> </tr> ';
  echo ' <tr> <td ></td></tr> ';
  echo '<tr><td height="49" id="Footer" style="background-image: url(img/bk03.gif); background-repeat: x;"> &nbsp; </td> </tr> ';
  echo '</table>';
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi now the table is showing with the background but the file menu.php is not inculde in the right place(the 2 TR) it show in the top of the table

Answer (score 1):

use the `''` in echo if there  is not any php variable and using the html so you wont need to escape the `"` in html tag like `href=\"#\"` or use like `echo '<a href="#">'.$link.'</a>';`

like echo '';

and use the `""` if there is php variable with the html tag

like `echo "<a href=\"#\">{$link}</a>";` or like `echo "<a href=\"#\">".$link."</a>";`

so the correct will be

```
 echo ' <table width="800" border="0" align="center"> ';
  echo ' <tr> <td height="106" id="main" style="background-image: url(img/bk01.jpg); background-repeat: x;"> </td> </tr> ';
  echo ' <tr> <td >   </td> </tr> ';
  echo ' <tr><td height="606" id="main" style="background-image: url(img/bk02.jpg); background-repeat: x;" >';  

  include 'menu.php' ;

  echo '</td> </tr> ';
  echo ' <tr> <td ></td></tr> ';
  echo' <tr><td height="49" id="Footer" style="background-image: url(img/bk03.gif); background-repeat: x;"> &nbsp; </td> </tr> ';
  echo'</table>';
```

Comment: chainge the internal "" to '' works fine but the include menu.php is not showing in the right place it sow in the top of the table.

Comment: @Apocaliptica61 sorry  check this out now i missed a '

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape quotes, or use a combination of single and double.

eg.

```
echo " <table width='800' border='0' align='center'> ";
```

OR

```
echo " <table width=\"800\" border=\"0\" align=\"center\"> ";
```